# axios.delete no envía los datos al método destroy en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
 <form action="#" method="post" role="form" class='forms' id="frmDeleteRoundCategory">
         {{ csrf_field() }}
         <input type="hidden" name="id_round" id='id_round' />
         <input type="hidden" name="id_category" id='id_category' />

          <p class="alert alert-danger">
              ¿ Eliminar la ronda <strong class="round"></strong> de la categoría  <strong class="category"></strong>?
          </p>

          <div class="button-group modal-footer" >
               <button  type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="btn btn-default">
                    <i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cerrar
               </button>
               <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-danger">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Eliminar
               </button>
         </div>
</form>
```

Los datos del formulario los envio por JS

```
  //DELETE
  $("#frmDeleteRoundCategory").submit(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 

      axios.delete("/round_category/" + $("#frmDeleteRoundCategory #id_round").val(), $(this).serialize())
            .then(function (response) {                         
                toastr.success(response.data);
            });  
  });
```

La ruta la tengo definida como:

> Route::resource('round_category', 'RoundCategoryController');

Y tengo el método destroy en el controlador:

```
public function destroy(Request $r, $id_round) {            
        dd($r->all());       
}
```

Al enviar los datos, el dd() me muestra un array vacío [].

Probé haciendo console.log($(this).serialize()); y me muestra bien los datos:

> _token=kvvSzXwBABQFjami6EHXxYmtXQtxe7AgKYvpu24y&id_round=5&id_category=13

Tengo otros 5 ABM con el metodo axios.delete copiado tal cual y funcionan perfectos. Solo tengo problema con esta Delete, donde axios no esta mandando los datos o hay algo que no estoy viendo. Porque siguiendo los pasos tengo todo definido:

1)Tengo la ruta definida Route:resource...
2)Capturo el evento con js y envio los datos con axios.delete
3)El llamado llega al metodo destroy, pero sin los datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas `axios.delete` tienes que usar `params` en vez de `data`,`data` solo está disponible para `PUT`, `POST` y `PATCH`.

Con ello, tu código quedaría como esto:

```
axios.delete("/round_category/" + $("#frmDeleteRoundCategory #id_round").val(), params: $(this).serializeArray()}})
            .then(function (response) {                         
                toastr.success(response.data);
            });
```

Comment: Me anduvo. Ahora al hacer $request->input('form') me trae 
"_token=A5akZdlclcKWQE36WxPTGzQKu0xKldLjJIGrd9Bb&id_round=1&id_category=1" como recupero el id_round por ejemplo de la cadena?

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta, he cambiado el método 'serialize' por `serializeArray`, el cual retorna un diccionario con los datos del formulario, ahora puedes obtener los campos como `$request->input('id_round') `

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!